# Kinds of arrays in java

Tags: java

So I need to assign multiple values to one value of an array in Java. Such as having the number 0 of an array having three different numbers associated with it, but keeping them separate.

My bad, I forgot to mention that the integer values that will be assigned are in separate classes and are based on user input from other classes.

Comment: Store an object reference whose class holds the 3 or more elements you want/need.

Comment: Give some sample i/p and o/p.

Answer (score 3):

Create custom class

```
 class CustomClass{
  public int a;
  // so on 
 }

List<CustomClass> myList=new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
```

Another way is to convert the 3 values to string and concat them as 1-2-3  so that string will have 1-2-3 ...Split the string and convert back them into int...(harder but yes possible).

Answer (score 3):

Use a two-dimensional array. e.g.

```
int[][] multiArray = new int[3][3];

// either
int[] firstValue = {0,1,2};
multiArray[0] = firstValue;

// or
multiArray[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};
```

Which, when printed, will give:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Static initialization

```
int[] anArray = { 
    100, 200, 300,
    400, 500, 600, 
    700, 800, 900, 1000
};
```